# Is there any benefit to buy a Mac over Windows PC just to make and test HTML5 web apps and sites for iphone even if I'm already having iPhone?

Tags: iphone, html, mobile-website, javascript-framework

I know native app development for iOS is not possible on windows but for Web Apps Development it's possible on all OS.

Is there any benefit buy a iMac or Macbook over Windows PC just to make and test HTML5 + CSS3 Web apps and sites for iphone? **If I'm already having iPhone**.

As I already have iphone and ipad so i think I don't need Emulators of iOS SDK.

1) Can having Mac improve productivity in making Web Apps **not Native apps**?

2) Are there any better Web Development tools available on MAC to make **Mobile Websites and Web Apps** for iPhone compare to windows?

3) Currently whenever I want to test something on iphone safari I upload first all files into my ftp (online) then i open the url from iphone safari. But If I buy mac and install Apple SDK, can I run local html files directly on iPhone emulator.

**Note: My question is not related to making iOS native applications.**

Comment: atleast it would be more secured ;)

Comment: Not really. But developers who think like Mac users tend to create UIs that are significantly more appreciated by their Mac-using audience.

Comment: @Cody, but he's not targeting the Mac audience and the iOS UI is very different to Mac.

Comment: Its btw not a emulator but a simulator. So the simulators HTML rendering can be different from the one of a real device (its probably 99% the same but some things are just different on the simulator)

Comment: @JustSid - yes we can check that 1% difference later if I can check my html in Simulator without uploading the files to FTP each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest (I am a mac fan and always have been) if you are switching to mac for just for testing purposes it really wouldn't be worth it.  You said in your question that you have a an iPhone and iPad both of those can connect to a local network and you can preview on them.  Testing iPhone and iPad event on the iOS emulator really... sucks. You dont get any of the touch events or the slides so you really do need the real thing.  I just finished developing a full HTML5 webapp for the iPad/phone and I had to go out and buy an iPad for testing; the simulator would not cut it at all.

Now on the other hand if you want to switch for a development environment I have always been a fan of OSX.  For two main reasons

1. The fact that the development tools
   for mac are amazing, Coda, TextMate,
   Sequel Pro, and CSS Editor alone
   make my computer worth it.
2. It's UNIX, if you are a web designer
   or developer who does not dabble in
   unix then this does not matter but I
   manage servers all over the world
   for about 30 different clients and
   the fact that OSX is UNIX underneath
   makes getting in and out, scripting,
   and moving files sooo easy. Try scp
   with putty... it's no fun.

I hope this helps,

TL;DR version: For testing don't buy one it's not worth it. For the full package do it.

Comment: +1 very good answer. How to connect iphone to see local preview?

Answer (score 2):

If there are any better tools, it's not worth the cost of a Mac. You're best sticking with your PC, especially if you've never used a Mac before (or if you've not used one often),
Simple things like the window controls being on the "wrong" side of the window and not doing the same thing as their window counterparts ("maximise" is not the same on Mac) can cause annoyance and cost time.

Testing files locally isn't exactly the same as remotely, and the emulator will not match the iphone, as the user agent strings are different. Also the simulator is designed for native apps primarily so I'm betting the Safari on it is not exactly the same as on a device. Basically you can't beat the device.

Answer (score 1):

No.  if you are already comfortable using a PC then stick with it.  There aren't any better web development tools on the mac then the pc (personal tastes aside).

Comment: I suppose *anything* can be dismissed as simply "personal tastes". Sometimes, I think [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/) and [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/) are enough to merit my switching development completely to the Mac. Simply beautiful UI, amazing functionality, unsurpassed on the Windows platform. The Windows apps I use every day feel normal, almost right, but they have a name for that: Stockholm syndrome.